# Add click event on window, but ignore all links that start with https

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add on click event on window, but to exclude all links that start with https.
I tried something, but I'm not sure in which direction to go. For example

```
$(window).not("a[href^='https']").click(function(){
    console.log('Clicked');    
});
```

or

```
$(window).click(function(evt){
    //somehow check click argument to inspect outgoing URL maybe?        
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()`, because you have prevent parent click event on click of link

```
$(window).click(function(){
    console.log('Clicked');    
})
$("a[href^='https']").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('This was a link');    
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/76/)

Comment: Ty, this is what I needed. Accept in 4 mins.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
$(window).on('click', 'a', function(evt){
    if(this.href.indexOf('https') == 0)
        return;

    //other logic here
});
```

with the `on` method I attach the event to the window, but it only fires when it is executed on an element that matches the `a` selector. Then I check the element `href` property to see if it starts with https, if it does I exit early on.

Comment: Nice solution, but this wont register clicks on non `a` tags I need them all. Upvoted, but I'll accept other answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use window.location.protocol:

```
$(window).click(function(evt){
    if (window.location.protocol != "https:"){
      alert("clicked but not https");
    }
    else{
      alert("clicked and yes https");
    }
});
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fn4Lk263/